# Application(.exe) created in visual studio 2012 in not working

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Am using Windows 8.1. I have created an application in visual c++,CLR project in visual studio 2012. The .exe file is working fine in my computer. But when i run the .exe file in another computer its not opening/working. It is not showing any error messages or app crash report. I don't know where the problem can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Did you check Windows-logs if there is any error reported? Check if all necessary are on board.

Comment: Yes i have checked and there is no error reported.

Comment: Are **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio** installed on target computer (respectively are the of the package included shipped)?

Comment: ya i installed it now but its not working.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vm5cs1xemos4w9/Parking%20Assistance.exe
the above link is the exe file

Comment: when i download it from dropbox,it is showing some warning messages like the file is harmful select keep/discard the file. is it possible to void these warning messages

Comment: Sorry can`t test the exe at the moment. You should include some logging in your app. If there starts no process (did you control it in task manager?) there must be a more fundamental problem. :-/

Comment: Sorry i cant get you logging means in which way are you telling?

Comment: I mean Logging with log4net or something else. Let your application write some log-messages in a file, so that you come closer to the problem.